# URL Rewrite Module Questions

Tags: php, module, url-rewriting

I want to make a rewrite module in htaccess file something like below

```
http://example.com/index.php?tel=604-567-0909&cat=1&sort=2
```

to

```
http://example.com/604-567-0909/?cat=1&sort=2
```

so `$_GET` will be

```
$_GET[tel] = 604-567-0909
$_GET[cat] = 1 
$_GET[sort] = 2
```

How would this rule look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like this if you only wanted to accept numbers and dashes in the `tel` field:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9\-]+)/$ index.php?tel=$1 [L]
```

The other values in the query string would be carried over automatically, and this rule would work without them just fine.